# Installing signal handler inside handler of another signal, is it possible?

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

I have to write a stack crawler/traceback code. I am installing my own sigsegv handler. All works fine as long as my traceback is not called from another handler.

More precisely, if my traceback is called from another handler (lets say for SIGALRM) where that handler blocks all other signals , my handler for sigsegv does not get invoked. I understand that this is be because of the previous handler blocking all other signals (please correct me if i am wrong). I want to understand, if my handler for sigsegv will even be installed or not? Because even though the my handler is not invoked the pending bit for sigsegv should be set for that process and once the current handler (for SIGALRM) finishes at least that time my handler should be invoked.

Also, is there a way to I can ensure that SIGSEGV will be caught in this case where traceback is being called from another handler which has blocked that signal.

Thanks.

Comment: what happened when you **tried it**? Good luck.

Comment: My handler was not executed, but the process ended with the default "Segmentation Fault (core dump)" . I was reseting the mask in my traceback using sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&maks,NULL); , where 'mask' had all signals except SIGSEGV, i expected this to unblock sigsegv and in process continue to block all other signals, but it turns out I have to explicitly do "sigprocmask SIG_UNBLOCK" for sigsegv. It worked then.

Comment: Can you post your code?